# scope-contacts-google and unity-scope-spotify is missing packages which won't be installed

Tags: lenses, google, spotify, scopes

When I try to install scope-contacts-google and unity-scope-spotify, it says that is misses

gir1.2-dee-0.5 for google

gir1.2-unity-4.0 and gir1.2-dee-0.5 for spotify.

When I try to install these missing packages, it tells me I have a newer version installed. What's wrong, and what do I do?

Comment: What is the version of your Ubuntu? Developers must upgrade their application

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to specify. I'm running the Presice beta.

Answer (score 1):

### scope-contacts-google

For this the dependency package `gir1.2-dee-0.5` is already available in Ubuntu Precise and Oneiric.

### unity-scope-spotify

For this dependency package `gir1.2-dee-0.5` is present in precise, but `gir1.2-unity-4.0` isn't present because precise contains Unity 5.10

Instead package `gir1.2-unity-5.0` is present in Ubuntu Precise.

It would be good to ask the scope developers to update their scopes to use the latest packages as dependencies

Comment: +1. Just that `gir1.2-dee-1.0` replaced `gir1.2-dee-0.5` in 12.04 and `gir1.2-unity-5.0` replaced `gir1.2-unity-4.0`.

Comment: Looks I need to do an update again :)